# how to scan a document before uploading in spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I want to give a button of scan so that it opens up a scan feature and user can scan the document and then upload that file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an API to control scanner device , better go with Morena API . You can find the relevant information about the Morena API [here](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html)

Comment: I dont want virus scan i want scanning a file from scanner option.that when i click on the button it give the option scanned the file from the scanner and after that i can upload it

Comment: Please come up with the clear question.Though, i have updated my answer .Hope it helps !

Comment: how can i access scanner and scan document when triggering a button in jsp

Comment: As i said , Using Morena API is the solution . Check http://www.codepool.biz/java-twain-with-dynamic-net-twain-and-jni4net.html